# Transparent Data Encryption (TDE)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

While encrypting the database the following error has occurred:

```
Transparent Data Encryption is not available in the edition of this SQL Server instance. See books online for more details on feature support in different SQL      Server edition.
```

I used the below queries for encryption.
use master

```
 SELECT * FROM sys.symmetric_keys WHERE name LIKE '%MS_DatabaseMasterKey%'
 CREATE CERTIFICATE TDECertificate WITH SUBJECT = 'SQL Server TDE Certificate'
 SELECT * FROM sys.certificates where [name] = 'TDECertificate'
 create database testEncrypt
 use testEncrypt
 CREATE DATABASE ENCRYPTION KEY WITH ALGORITHM = AES_256 ENCRYPTION BY SERVER CERTIFICATE TDECertificate
```

Answer (score 4):

TDE is only supported on Datacenter and Enterprise editions for SQL 2008/R2. You will need to purchase the relevant licence to gain access to TDE functionality.

Source: http://sqlmag.com/sql-server/transparent-data-encryption-faqs

Answer (score 0):

There are two third party products that offer Transparent Data Encryption to all versions and editions of SQL Server, including Express. One is NetLib Encryptionizer and the other is DBDefence. However, they work very differently. Encryptionizer sits between SQL and the operating system, while DBDefence injects code into the running SQL process in memory using the (now defunct, I believe) Detours SDK. (Disclaimer: I am from [NetLib Security](https://netlibsecurity.com))